# Success to install mysqlclient with pip. But not exists mysqlclient in virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, centos

I want to install mysqlclient with pip in virtual environment. That is success...? But I can not find that module in virtual environment. Why?

```
# cd /root
# source venv/bin/activate
# pip freeze
# pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.3.13

# pip freeze
# pip uninstall mysqlclient
Skipping mysqlclient as it is not installed.

# which pip
/root/venv/bin/pip
```

Comment: Tangentially, doing these things in `/root` is almost certainly the wrong way.

Comment: instead using root, you should take the path to your own directory /myuser/